# SDL_SetVideoMode Desired vs. Obtained

Tags: c, sdl

I'm writing programs in C that use SDL for graphics. I have my program optimized for writing video in a 32 bits per pixel mode. I just go along each scan line writing blue, green, red, skip, blue, green, red, skip, blue, green, red, skip (skipping those extra bytes in the 32 bpp format). Is there any chance this could fail? Could SDL deny me 32 bpp and give me something else instead? Could the byte offsets of different colors end up in a different order and screw up my program?

Comment: I would kinda like an answer to this... So I'm going to start a bounty.

Comment: If the answer you got is acceptable, you should not just accept it but also assign the bounty. Otherwise the bounty will go unawarded.

Comment: Yeah, I just got an automated E-mail in my inbox to that effect. Thanks for the reminder, I wasn't aware that selecting an answer didn't automatically take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SDL_SetVideoMode` by default ensures you get your required pixel depth. Even if the pixel depth is not available, it emulates it virtually (they call this "shadow surface"). Ofcourse, this can be disabled with the `SDL_ANYFORMAT` flag.

For more information, refer the following wiki

http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetVideoMode

I am also suspecting that there might be a perfomance degradation if the depth is being emulated. Not sure on that.

Also with regards to your logic, I am not sure why you are doing such a native scan line manipulation. If your application really requires such control, then you are probably better off writing OpenGL or DirectX  specific code and interface them with SDL through library calls. You can google up for more on interfacing OpenGL or DirectX with SDL.

Comment: Whether or not this is the best way, will the byte order always be the same?

Comment: Although I have no evidence on the matter, my opinion is that the byte order will remain the same for sake of consistency. Given that it is going out of the way to emulate it

Comment: Ah, I guess selecting an answer doesn't automatically award bounty, there you go!